# I have multiple "none" partitions, why?

Tags: 10.04, disk, disk-management

When I type "df -h" in my terminal, the following is the output:

```
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1              38G  7.1G   29G  20% /
none                  498M  248K  497M   1% /dev
none                  502M  1.1M  501M   1% /dev/shm
none                  502M  104K  502M   1% /var/run
none                  502M     0  502M   0% /var/lock
none                  502M     0  502M   0% /lib/init/rw
```

FWIW, this is a VM image running Ubuntu 10.04.4...

What's up with all the none partitions, and how can I combine them all (assuming they're not needed)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are all virtual file systems created by the Linux kernel. They contain device nodes and other directories required for UNIX programs to function properly.

This page looks like a comprehensive guide to the UNIX file system: http://bid.ankara.edu.tr/yardim/linux.install.guide/node116.html